# There isn't enough memory by deleting rows

Tags: excel, vba

My macro just stopped working. By the row `Worksheets("ASD").Rows("5:9").Delete` I get the error "there isn't enough memory to complete this action try using less data or closing other applications". Im sure I have enough memory.

Comment: How many columns have data?

Comment: 30 columns, and 5000 rows but I just dont get why it stopped working.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? Maybe another program is eating up your memory.

Comment: yes, rebooting doesnt help :(

Comment: Note that you didn't tell how many sheets you have, and how much data they hold, and you didn't tell either what else your macro is doing. Are there big global or local objects in your macro, for instance? Anything that could eat up memory? Not that even if the error happens on this very line, the problem may lie elsewhere.

Comment: Is this code in an event handler like `Worksheet_Change` or is it in a normal Sub/Function?

Answer (score 0):

Two options that might help you. Specifically this error is often caused when you save your excel files in an old format. Such as  97-2003 version. Simply Save the file as a newer version. This helped most of the times I expierenced so far.

Alternatively (if the above isnt the case) Go to the Excel Options/Advanced/General and tick the Box "Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)".
This should fix the issue in any case.

Good luck!

Comment: My file is saved as .xlsm , the newest version. The solution with ticking this Box has not helped unfortunatelly :(

Comment: Please resatart you PC and try again if you havent done so after ticking the box :)